# How can I call a C# program from Delphi and gather a return value?

Tags: c#, delphi

At the moment, both programs are still simple console applications. This will change later on, since this is only a test if it's even possible to call a C# program from Delphi.

Currently my delphi application looks like this:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

begin
  try
    // CALL C# PROGRAM
    // PRINT RETURN VALUE
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

And my C# program looks like this:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // return hello world to the delphi program
        }
    }
}
```

My initial goal is call the C# application, return some value from C# to Delphi and then print the return value in Delphi.

I would highly appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call C# dll from Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174584/call-c-sharp-dll-from-delphi)

Comment: @fatemehyadollahzadeh What exactly is DDL?